# Selenium IEDriverServer.exe - The browser opens up but .SendKeys() isn't working

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, nunit

I'm using Selenium and NUnit to test multiple browsers - FF and Chrome work fine, but IE just opens up the browser to my Login page and just proceeds to hang there doing nothing.

I'm using the most recent versions of the Drivers.  Anyone else have this problem, and hopefully a solution?  IE is the browser that we *really* need to test.

Thanks much. :-)

Comment: Which version of IE/Windows are you testing on? Doesn't Selenium require that you reconfigure Protected Mode or put the target site in the Trusted Zone?

Comment: Did you set the Protected Mode settings to all the same value?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry it took me a bit to get back on here.

I'm using IE 10, Windows 7 64 bit.  I can't put the target site in the trusted zone as it has to log in(so no https, at least not at first).  All protected mode settings are off.

Any other ideas?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Disable protected mode in IE browser and disable it for all four icon

```
   1) Internet
   2) trusted 
   3) Local Intranet
   4) restricted site

Tools > internet options > security > Enable protected mode
```

Enable protected mode check box, check image[image]

Comment: I did try that just now, still not getting anything to happen.  Keeps failing, unable to find the login username field...

Thanks though.